# Am I using pyglets Sprite.delete() wrong?

Tags: python, sprite, pyglet

I want to remove a pyglet sprite. I am trying it using delete() method on the sprite object.
Following test script ...

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()

x = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img=pyglet.image.load('resource/icon.png'))
draw_objects = [x]


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    for obj in draw_objects:
        obj.draw()


@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol == pyglet.window.key.DELETE:
        print('deleting')
        global x
        x.delete()


pyglet.app.run()
```

... produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Finn\Data\PythonProjects\_tests\firstPyglet\test.py", line 24, in <module>
    pyglet.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\Finn\Data\PythonProjects\_tests\firstPyglet\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\__init__.py", line 107, in run
    event_loop.run()
  File "C:\Users\Finn\Data\PythonProjects\_tests\firstPyglet\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 167, in run
    timeout = self.idle()
  File "C:\Users\Finn\Data\PythonProjects\_tests\firstPyglet\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 243, in idle
    window.dispatch_event('on_draw')
  File "C:\Users\Finn\Data\PythonProjects\_tests\firstPyglet\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\__init__.py", line 1333, in dispatch_event
    if EventDispatcher.dispatch_event(self, *args) != False:
  File "C:\Users\Finn\Data\PythonProjects\_tests\firstPyglet\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\event.py", line 408, in dispatch_event
    if handler(*args):
  File "C:\Users\Finn\Data\PythonProjects\_tests\firstPyglet\test.py", line 13, in on_draw
    obj.draw()
  File "C:\Users\Finn\Data\PythonProjects\_tests\firstPyglet\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\sprite.py", line 672, in draw
    self._group.set_state_recursive()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_state_recursive'
```

Is there a problem with my code, or is something wrong with pyglet?

Comment: A [mini example](https://gist.github.com/Torxed/15c09b34f8ccea2d7c937e834a68f7e4) of how references work, as I think you FinnK either has a background in C/C++ or got taught something misleading at some point. Since the reference of the object is copied into multiple places, deleting one reference won't remove them all as BlackFenix06 points out and the solution below should work for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `draw_objects.remove(x)` after `x.delete()`. The error is caused by the fact that you are trying to draw a sprite in the appropriate function that has been previously deleted, but has not removed its variable from the drawing list.

```
@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    global x
    if symbol == pyglet.window.key.DELETE:
        if x in draw_objects:
            print('deleting')
            x.delete()
            draw_objects.remove(x)
```

Comment: Seems to be a general python mistake, since pyglet's `.delete()` does not substitute removing a python object from a list it is included in. In the general case, when you try to invoke pyglet methods on "pyglet deleted" objects ― pyglet objects that you have invoked their `delete()` method ― and then try using them again, you will get those cryptic `'NoneType' object has no attribute ...` errors. It manifests like that because pyglet marks certain attributes of a pyglet deleted object as None, and of course you're not supposed to use them after deleting them.